# Define a variable for use it in the import path for Angular Typescript projects

Tags: angular, typescript

I was not sure how to write the title of the question but what I want to know is if it is possible to assign a project folder and use it like when we import things from `@angular`.

Example, instead of this:

```
import {myProvider} from '../some/path/relative/to/this/file/providers/my-provider.service
```

I would like to do this:

```
import {myProvider} from '@providers/provider.service
```

is this possible?

Comment: by `title` what you mean?

Comment: The title of the question

Comment: `@angular` is package scope. Angular team publishes packages on NPM under this scope. And `@angular` packages are loaded then from node_modules. It has nothing to do with local paths. I don't think that this was your intention.

Comment: @estus what I want to achieve (if is it possible) is to have a cleaner way to reference the `models`, `providers` and `components` directories when a project structure is complex. The closest thing that I have found is the imports from `node_modules`

Comment: You can do this if you modularize your app and publish it to NPM (likely as private packages). Otherwise you need to make this with Webpack, as linked question explains. Typescript alone can't help.

Comment: Yes I am looking at this posts and I have found really good info. I did not have the correct keywords to do a correct search and I was pointing in the complete wrong direction. I suppose I have to delete this question since it is not a correct question?

Comment: @distante I guess you should. Feel free to come up with more specific question if you will still have problems with approach explained for Webpack. Btw, here's what you confused that @ with, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope